# How to properly debug Python in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I am confused with the `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal` command. In my VsCode (Windows 11). I have two commands with the same shortcut `Shift+Enter`.

One is launching an Interactive Jupyter notebook (awful). The other sends it to a Python Terminal (better). My ideal case would be to send it to an Ipython terminal.

How to configure that properly?

[image]

Comment: Try using pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "IPython",

"IPython": {
  "path": "C:\\Work\\python3.10\\.venv\\Scripts\\ipython.exe"  //The path to the ipython.exe, please take care of which ipython you have selected, this means which python interpreter selected in the terminal.
},
```